# Getting additional input from SlackClient using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, slack, slack-api

One of the issues is I’m running into is getting additional data from a command in slack. I️ don’t want to use Slash commands because I️ can’t expose my localhost to the world.

Example:

```
@mybot do
```

Will return, let’s say “I’m doing something”. However I️ want to be able to do something like

```
@mybot do 2
```

Where 2 is a parameter in the back end. Basically what I’m trying to do is have it where the user can say `@mybot do 2` and it will get data from the database where the ID is 2. You could make it a 3, 4, 5 etc and the command will pull the information from the database. I️ have found where I️ can make it match the exact “do” command, though I️ can’t get it to read the follow on data. I️ was following [this tutorial](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/build-first-slack-bot-python.html). Any help will be great.

> if you see weird symbols it’s because I’m doing this from an iPhone and I️ have that stupid bug where the turns I️ (eye) into I️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions to extract arguments from text. I hope this will help.

```
import re


def handle_command(command, channel):
    response = "Not sure what you mean. Use the *" + EXAMPLE_COMMAND + \
               "* command with numbers, delimited by spaces."

    match = re.match("do (?P<arg>\S+)", command)
    if match:
        arg = match.groupdict('arg')
        response = "Wow! My argument is: " + arg

    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel,
                          text=response, as_user=True)
```

Comment: I’ll give this a try when I️ get back to work tonight!

Answer (score 0):

**How to get "additional information"**

You will get the complete input string in the text property, e.g. `"do 2"`. All you need to do is split the string into words. I am not a Python developer, but apparently [split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) will do the job.

**Exposing your localhost**

I would strongly recommend to go ahead and expose your localhost with a VPN tunnel. It makes development so much easier. You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to securely expose your localhost to Slack.

**"Dont want to use slash commands"**

You will always need an app (e.g. Python script) on an exposed host for any custom functionality to work with Slack. Actually, slash commands are easier to implement then Event API and RTM, so I would recommend it for your case.

Comment: Is ngrok a permanent solution? How secure is it? If it’s not permanent, what can I️ do in replacement of it as I️ have to keep the bot itself running inside the network.

Comment: sure. Its a product and its meant to be used as a permanent solution. However, if you want to use it permanently you will need to look for a payed plan. The free plan will only give you a temporary URL. However,  if you plan to run your bot permanently, e.g. as a public Slack app I would recommend to deploy your app on a public web server or cloud service, while using ngrok for your development.